# Problems setting / reading cookie in django

Tags: ajax, django, rest, cookies

I'm trying to set a persistent cookie for several consecutive requests. The idea is that if a request does not contain the cookie in the first place, a uuid4 identifier is set in a cookie under 'mykey' and the response is sent. This all happens via requests made to a REST api from a javascript client.

I can see the cookie when inspecting the response on my browser, but if I issue a second request—which should **not** set a new cookie, as 'mykey' is already populated—the cookie is reset with a new uuid4 identifier.

This is the code:

```
def some_view(request):
    cookie = request.get_signed_cookie('mykey', salt='foobar', default=False)
    # do stuff
    response = HttpResponse(content='foo')
    if not cookie:
        value = str(uuid.uuid4())
        response.set_signed_cookie('mykey', value, salt='foobar')
    return response
```

Any ideas? Thnx!

A.

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting this cookie instead of just using the session framework?

Comment: Yes, I want the cookie to stay in the browser for a long period of time. The thing is this is an ajax request that will set/read the cookie. For what I've been reading, it seems that is not possible due to browser restrictions. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

With the signed cookies, you are probably running into problems with [HTTPOnly](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/). You could try this:

```
set_signed_cookie(key, value, salt='', httponly=False)
```

Comment: But wouldn't this only affect me accessing the cookie at browser level? I'm trying to set it and read it both at server level. Or do I have to explicitly set/retrieve cookie at browser level and then send cookie as an argument?